# android phone number verification using broadcast receiver

Tags: android, sms, broadcastreceiver

I need to verify the mobile number the user is entered. For that , I am sending a message from  his mobile to number he entered with some special code in the message body. I have registered a broadcast receiver for incoming messages and once I got the message I am verifying both the number and the special code. If both are matching , I am confirming mobile number is valid.

But, if user enters some other mobile number , the broadcast receiver for incoming message will not executed. What is the best way to handle this?

Comment: In this case you have to handle it manually, need to send the code to that number and show one EditText where user can enter that code. This is same whatsapp is doing i think.

Comment: watsapp is doing automatically, not manuaaly

Answer (score 0):

> But, if user enters some other mobile number , the broadcast receiver for incoming message will not executed. What is the best way to handle this?

This depends on what precisely you want your verification to function.

If you want to allow verification via another device (e.g., your app runs on device A, user enters phone number of device B and receives message there) you'll have to provide a way for the user to manually input the received code.

Otherwise, if you require that the phone number entered is currently used by the device your app runs on you'll have to additionally implement error handling in your app. This is not restricted to users entering wrong/different phone numbers. Instead, you have to handle any case where you don't receive a message a certain time after the phone number was entered. Generally, you could prompt the user to enter the phone number again (instructing him to make sure that it belongs to the device) after some time. However, please also check that

1. You have successfully sent the message
2. The device can receive the message, e.g., airplane mode is not enabled

and act accordingly.